# Reflectively instantiate class with constructor which takes Enum

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, enums

I have a superclass OpCode and subclasses Add/And..etc

I am trying to reflectively construct the subclasses based on their class name string. The constructor takes an enum defined in the superclass.

I am trying:

```
OpCode theOpCode = (OpCode) Class.forName("com.sstangle.opCodes." + opCodeName).getConstructor(OpCode.OpEn.class).newInstance(opEn);
```

which results in

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sstangle.opCodes.Add.<init>(com.sstangle.opCodes.OpCode$OpEn)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
```

The Add Class is

```
public class Add extends OpCode {
    Add(final OpEn opEn) {
        super(opEn);
        this.assemblyCommand = "ADD";
    }
}
```

The OpCode Class is

```
public abstract class OpCode {
    OpCode(final OpEn opEn) {
        this.opEn = opEn;
    }
    public static enum OpEn {
        I, MI, MR, RM, ZO
    }
}
```

How do I correctly access the constructor taking the enum?

Thanks

Comment: That particular class doesn't have such a constructor taking an `com.sstangle.opCodes.OpCode$OpEn`. Can you show the constructors of the `Add` class?

Comment: @AndyTurner updated.

Comment: The problem is that the ctor isn't public. Try making it public, or using `getDeclaredConstructor`.

Comment: The *ctor* needs to be public, not just the class.

Comment: doh, yup that worked.Thanks

Comment: Nit: "reflexive" and "reflective" don't mean the same thing. This is "reflective".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [source code of `Class.getConstructor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getConstructor%28java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29):

```
public Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
    throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    checkMemberAccess(Member.PUBLIC, Reflection.getCallerClass(), true);
    return getConstructor0(parameterTypes, Member.PUBLIC);
}
```

That `Member.PUBLIC` tells the `getConstructor0` method only to return a public constructor.

```
private Constructor<T> getConstructor0(Class<?>[] parameterTypes,
                                    int which) throws NoSuchMethodException
{
    Constructor<T>[] constructors = privateGetDeclaredConstructors((which == Member.PUBLIC));
    for (Constructor<T> constructor : constructors) {
        if (arrayContentsEq(parameterTypes,
                            constructor.getParameterTypes())) {
            return getReflectionFactory().copyConstructor(constructor);
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchMethodException(getName() + ".<init>" + argumentTypesToString(parameterTypes));
}
```

where the `privateGetDeclaredConstructors` takes a boolean parameter called `publicOnly`:

```
private Constructor<T>[] privateGetDeclaredConstructors(boolean publicOnly)
```

Either make the constructor `public`, or use `getDeclaredConstructor` instead.

Comment: You mean constructor by "ctor"?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz yep.

Comment: "ctor" is the standard abbreviated form of "constructor".

Comment: @LewBloch it is, and it's what I tend to type quickly, but I don't mind expanding it.

Comment: i just googled it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯